# Is the Supergirl/Flash crossover understandable enough without watching the whole first season of Supergirl?

Tags: the-flash, arrowverse, supergirl

I know everything from Arrowverse but I am not following Supergirl. Only checked it's [leaked pilot](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/are-there-any-differences-between-supergirls-leaked-episode-and-the-broadcast-o). Do I need to see the whole Supergirl till the crossover or is the basic knowledge of Supergirl + pilot episode enough to understand the crossover episode?

Comment: Nah. All you really need to know is that Supergirl's gained a bad reputation after going a bit crazy (due to red kryptonite). There's a lot of other plot going on that you'll be unaware of (Kara's ill-chosen romantic triangle) but nothing you'll notice or really care about.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure you need to watch the crossover episode to get any additional story for The Flash, so you could give it a miss entirely.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Agreed. It's a completely self-contained episode from his perspective. He doesn't bring anything back with him, physically or emotionally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The episode doesn't go into much lore, and the basic premisses are explained to the Audience via explanations to The Flash/Barry.

The biggest issues would be:

> How/Why Livewire became Livewire, why Silver Banshee hates Kara, and the bulk of the Kara/Jimmy UST.

But Callista Flockhart's character sums those up nicely (well, condescendingly) as well.